# Markitup always shows html special chars after reading from db

Tags: php, javascript, markitup

In my db I'm storing something like this:

```
<p>something</p>
```

and then i'm loading that value into a markitup editor, but it keeps showing up like this

```
&lt;p&gt;something&lt;/p&gt;
```

How can I make it so it shows `<p>something</p>` in the markitupeditor?

Settings:

```
// used for the markitup editor
     mySettings = {
        nameSpace:      'html',
        onShiftEnter:   {keepDefault:false, replaceWith:'<br />\n'},
        onCtrlEnter:    {keepDefault:false, openWith:'\n<p>', closeWith:'</p>'},
        onTab:          {keepDefault:false, replaceWith:'    '},
        markupSet:  [   
            {name:'Heading 2', key:'2', openWith:'<h2(!( class="[![Class]!]")!)>', closeWith:'</h2>', placeHolder:'Your title here...' },
            {name:'Paragraph', openWith:'<p(!( class="[![Class]!]")!)>', closeWith:'</p>'  },
            {name:'Bold', key:'B', openWith:'(!(<strong>|!|<b>)!)', closeWith:'(!(</strong>|!|</b>)!)' },
            {name:'Italic', key:'I', openWith:'(!(<em>|!|<i>)!)', closeWith:'(!(</em>|!|</i>)!)'  },
            {name:'Stroke through', key:'S', openWith:'<del>', closeWith:'</del>' },
            {separator:'---------------' },
            {name:'Bulleted List', openWith:'    <li>', closeWith:'</li>', multiline:true, openBlockWith:'<ul>\n', closeBlockWith:'\n</ul>'},
            {name:'Numeric List', openWith:'    <li>', closeWith:'</li>', multiline:true, openBlockWith:'<ol>\n', closeBlockWith:'\n</ol>'},
            {separator:'---------------' },
            {name:'Picture', key:'P', replaceWith:'<img src="[![Source:!:http://]!]" alt="[![Alternative text]!]" />' },
            {name:'Link', key:'L', openWith:'<a href="[![Link:!:http://]!]"(!( title="[![Title]!]")!)>', closeWith:'</a>', placeHolder:'Your text to link...' },
            {separator:'---------------' },
            {name:'Clean', className:'clean', replaceWith:function(markitup) { return markitup.selection.replace(/<(.*?)>/g, "") } },       
            {name:'Preview', className:'preview',  call:'preview'}
        ]
     }
```

Comment: Can you use [htmlspecialchars_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)?

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. I think there is something in the markitup code that is causing this.

Comment: Odd, I set a breakpoint on the [Demo](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/examples/html/) and the text is definitely normal HTML. Can you post your settings object?

Comment: Maybe it's something else, I tried that too and it seems fine.

Comment: Hmmm. The weird thing is that when I pull it from the db, it echoes fine, but when i'm doing it in the markitup editor, it shows the special chars rather than html tags. I'll keep digging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that my html tags were being converted to special chars was because of a parameter I had set on my the codeigniter `form_textarea` function.